# Accordion menu Behavior

Tags: jquery

I have created neat little script for my accordion menu and it is working almost fine. But I have some "glitch" issues:(

**Here's my problem:** try clicking **"Home"** link and then **"About Us"** link back and fourth and pay attention to bottom links (**"Service"** and **"Contact"** links) if you look closely you can see that those links are moving a bit (not much one or two pixels) while the animation is running.
Is there any way to fix this behavior? If possible i would like to keep the Html structure intact. Here's link the to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7f7J/) to show you my problem. Thank You!!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper{
display:block;
width:100px;
owerflow:hidden;
margin:0px auto;
margin-top:40px;
background-color:black;
position:relative;
}

.wrapper ul
{
list-style-type:none;
}

.wrapper ul li ul a{line-height:20px;}

a
{
color:white;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-decoration:none;
height:20px;
text-align:center;
line-height:20px;
}

.service{
background-color:red;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
outline:none;
}

.about{
background-color:red;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
outline:none;
}

.home{
background-color:red;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
outline:none;
}

.contact{
background-color:red;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
outline:none;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.wrapper ul li ul:first').addClass('active');

  $('.wrapper ul li ul').hide();
     $('a.home,a.about,a.service,a.contact').click(function() {
        if($('a.home,a.about,a.service,a.contact').next('ul').hasClass('active')) 
        {
     $('.active').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $(this).next('ul').addClass('active');
          $('.active:not(:animated)').stop().slideDown('slow');
        }
     });
});
</script>
</head>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a class="about" href="#">About Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a class="service" href="#">Service</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```